# not sure it's Git issue or Ubuntu for characher encoding

Tags: git, ubuntu

facing  issue while checking out code on Ubuntu , it replace © with Â© which in turn failing my build saying cannot find symbol.
no issues on window , 
can somebody give me clue

it's copyright statement in .java code , i am running my jenkins job which is cloning source from git repository and building it using mvn. my pom.xml explicitly set to compile such code

1.6
 UTF-8

This work fine when i run on windows , but when i do it on Ubuntu , it's get the java file with Â©  and my build fails

Comment: Sounds like originally utf-8 code being viewed by something that thinks it's windows-1252 encoded (or similar).

Answer (score 0):

You entered the copyright character with UTF-8 encoding, but are displaying the file or page in a single byte encoding such as Latin-1 or Windows-1252. You'll have to be a little more specific about what's going on. If you're producing HTML for a browser, try not to hard code (binary) non-ASCII characters in general code (i.e., non-"language" files), but use HTML entities instead.

Comment: it's copyright statement in .java code , i am running my jenkins job which is cloning source from git repository and building it using mvn. my pom.xml explicitly set to compile such code

<properties>
        <java.version>1.6</java.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>


This work fine when i run on windows , but when i do it on Ubuntu , it's get the java file with Â© and my build fails